# ¿Es posible controlar de alguna manera el estado de la memoria externa en Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, manejo-de-memoria

Tengo el siguiente código donde voy chequeando el estado de la memoria, mi pregunta es, de alguna forma ¿se puede cambiar ese estado en alguna parte de la aplicación?

```
    private TextView memCheck;
    private TextView showMemStatus;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        memCheck = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewMemCheck);
        showMemStatus = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewMemoria);
    }

    public void MemoryCheck(View view) {
        String estado= Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if(estado.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
            showMemStatus.setText("Memoria externa operativa para L/E ");
        else
        if(estado.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY))
            showMemStatus.setText("Memoria externa operativa sólo para lectura");
        else
            showMemStatus.setText("Memoria externa no operativa");
    }
}
```

Comment: A que te refieres con controlar el estado de la memoria externa?

Comment: Poder activarla o desactivarla

Comment: Entiendo, agregué una respuesta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

esto definitivamente no es posible por cuestiones de seguridad.

**No es permitido controlar de alguna manera el estado de la memoria externa en un dispositivo android, ya que se podría escribir código malicioso, el cual permitiría montar y desmontar la tarjeta SD del teléfono**, las únicas operaciones permitidas en la memoria de almacenamiento externa son leer y escribír datos.

Únicamente podemos leer el estado de la memoria externa en un dispositivo android.